# Searching Tri Data Structure

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have around 150,000 words loaded into a Trie data structure and want to search that. Each time I enter a new character in the searchBox, that will be pass as parameter for NextMatch.

For example: If I type 'Appl' then all words starting with 'Appl' will be returned. If then I enter character 'e' similarly all words starting with 'Apple' will be shown.

The problem is that when I remove the character 'e' then 'l' will be passed as parameter for NextMatch to Matcher method and founds something like 'Appll' but I want list of those words starting with 'Appl'.

Here is my code sniped

```
private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listboxWords1.Items.Clear();

    if (searchBox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        trie.Matcher.NextMatch(searchBox.Text.Trim().Last());
        foundWords = trie.Matcher.GetPrefixMatches(); //foundWords is List<string>
        for (int i = foundWords.Count - 1; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            listboxWords1.Items.Add(foundWords[i]);
        }

        foundWords = null;
        isFoundExact = trie.Matcher.IsExactMatch();
        if (isFoundExact)
            listboxWords1.Items.Add(trie.Matcher.GetExactMatch());
    }
    else
    {
        foundWords = null;
        trie.Matcher.ResetMatch();

    }
}
```

Implementation of Trie data structure  can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/typocalypse/source/browse/#hg/Trie)

Comment: The main problem is that I cannot determine whether a new character is entered or a character has been removed from the last of string. If I can determine that a character is removed I can tell it to search for remaining characters one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the API is unidirectional, but that's fine we can re compute the matches everytime from the beginning.

Trie's computational complexity is not that huge, so you won't feel any performance problems.

```
private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listboxWords1.Items.Clear();

    if (searchBox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        trie.Matcher.ResetMatch();//Reset the match

        foreach (char c in searchBox.Text)
            trie.Matcher.NextMatch(c); //Start the match from beginning 

        foundWords = trie.Matcher.GetPrefixMatches(); //foundWords is List<string>
        for (int i = foundWords.Count - 1; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            listboxWords1.Items.Add(foundWords[i]);
        }

        foundWords = null;
        isFoundExact = trie.Matcher.IsExactMatch();
        if (isFoundExact)
            listboxWords1.Items.Add(trie.Matcher.GetExactMatch());
    }
    else
    {
        foundWords = null;
        trie.Matcher.ResetMatch();    
    }
}
```

Not tested, but that should give you a idea. If user is typing very fast and you want to avoid computation very frequently, you can use some throttling logic to defer the search algorithm.

Comment: I have twitted you a programming question

Comment: @Hadi I suggest you to post a question here with relevant code. I'll try to help, and that question may help others also. Btw many folks here waiting just for helping others, so you will get good answers very soon.. If you want me to look at it, post the question and share the link. Thank you. I replied in twitter also :)